# Can SDL2 support multiple file dropping in its SDL_DROPFILE event?

Tags: sdl-2

I am about to implement an SDL application that should support multiple file dropping in its Window. But judging at this [SDL_DROPEVENT event](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DropEvent), it seems like it only support single file dropping.

Pardon, my googling result not able to find any related references about this multiple file dropping support. Any suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is that you try it out. My guess would be that it just gives you several `SDL_DROPFILE` events.

Comment: Actually, I have already tried this. And it gives only one SDL_DROPFILE event, with only the first file dropped was received as drop file parameter. Got to say, this is rather unfortunate for new comer like me in SLD2. There was talk about using X11 XDND protocol for this, but checking at the SDL2 source code, it still only support SDL_DROPFILE. http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=8800&sid=85d9be8b2138a2bc01abb8afd7c09b87

Comment: @swdev On my testing(SDL2+Mac), drop two files can get two SDL_DROPFILE events, each event take one file.

Comment: Hi, SDL has been updated to support multiple files drop in OSX. Pull the new changes and test it yourself. Works for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL has been updated to support multiple files drop in OSX. Pull the new changes and test it yourself. Works for me!